# How do I limit the source data for a chart using VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a module to stack plates onto rolltrailers, where the number of rolltrailers is unknown at start. In the process of outputting the report, it includes a chart to show how fully utilized the capacity of each trailer is.

[image: Utilisation chart]

However, because the number of RTs is unknown to start with, I'd like to add some code to adjust the source reference for the chart so it shows all the used trailers but no empty ones. The total number of rolltrailers is held in the `iRTNo` variable.

I first tried recording a macro and trying to include the variable in it, but that didn't work. My second attempt was this:

```
With wsReport.ChartObjects("Chart 3")
    .SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("RTTRACK").Range(Cells(2, 9), Cells(iRTNo + 1, 9))
End With
```

But that doesn't work either. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SetSourceData` should work but you aren't properly qualifying the `Cells` calls and you need to use the `Chart` property of the `Chartobject`:

```
With Sheets("RTTRACK")
    wsReport.ChartObjects("Chart 3").Chart.SetSourceData Source:=.Range(.Cells(2, 9), .Cells(iRTNo + 1, 9))
End With
```

Comment: Aaaah, so I'm coming at it from the wrong direction? Thanks, I'll try that. :-)

Comment: No, you were just missing a couple of things. ;)